# Combine filters to one with add classes

Tags: jquery, filter

I have one variable, but two different conditions for the filter with the addition of a class for each. You can somehow combine them, i.e. simplify the code so as not to write twice `p.filter(function() { return(` .. `.test($(this).html())); }).addClass(` .. `);`

```
var p = $('p:not(.wi-dialog,.wi-chapter)');
p.filter(function() { return ((/^[0-9.]+$/).test($(this).html())); }).addClass("wi-number");
p.filter(function() { return ((/^(END)+$/).test($(this).html())); }).addClass( "wi-end" );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do a simple `.each` ?

```js
var p = $('p:not(.wi-dialog,.wi-chapter)');

p.each(function() {
  const node = $(this);
  const html = node.html();
  const number = /^[0-9.]+$/.test(html);
  const end = /^(END)+$/.test(html);

  node
    .toggleClass('wi-number', number)
    .toggleClass('wi-end', end);
});
```

Comment: Works. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %`

Comment: yes that was a typo, i have already edited it.. it should be `$`

Comment: I will use it. Thanks!